# Putting using statement inside the namespace fails

Tags: c#, namespaces

I was trying to get some of the old code properly styled with stylecop. It asks for putting the using statements inside. It worked
well for all but one. I have reduced the problem to the below code.

```
namespace B.C
{
    using System;

    public class Hidden
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}

namespace A.B.C
{
    using B.C;

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Hidden().SayHello();
        }
    }
}
```

this gives compilation error Error

> "The type or namespace name 'Hidden' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

If I move **using B.C;** above the namespace A.B.C then it builds properly. The class Hidden is developed by different team and we cannot modify it.

Comment: Maybe `B.C` namespace is incorrectly evaluated to `A.B.C` when in namespace `A.B.C` scope? When at global scope it doesn't know about any namespace, so finds `B` first not assuming it's that `B` in `A` (`A.B`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you are inside the namespace `A`, then `B.C` will actually be `A.B.C`.

Use `global::` to specify that you are looking from the root:

```
using global::B.C;
```

Comment: It's also worth noting this works everywhere to escape namespace hell, not only in a using statement. (e.g. `new global::MyNS.BlahBlah()`)

Answer (score 2):

B.C is conflicting with A.B.C. You need to rename B.C to something else or specify it with `global`